# How to write ubuntu image to a bootable USB stick in a Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

My main computer running Windows 10 is showing BSoD, and I want to install Ubuntu in it. I have a spare Chromebook. How to make a bootable usb stick with it, which I can use to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Probably the question should be rephrased as how to write the Ubuntu iso to a usb stick in a Chromebook.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Ask Ubuntu community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you need to make the USB drive bootable.
You can download the ISO file of Ubuntu.
Download a software to make the USB drive bootable using the ISO.
I use a program called rufus or any other to make the USB drive bootable.

And then boot from the USB drive.
You don't need internet for the Ubuntu OS installation.

Comment: I guess the OP wanted to know how to make a bootable USB in Chromebook.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi oh, I have misunderstood